# How to properly modularize AngularJS App?

Tags: html, angularjs

How does one properly modularize an `Angularjs` app? I have an `HTML` page with separate parts, which I want to have separate controllers. At the moment I have one single controller, which serves the whole page. Different parts of the `HTML` page share the same scope data. Could someone provide a short and neat example with multiple controllers serving parts of the same page and sharing common scope data? I'm quite new to Angular.

Many thanks.

Comment: My personal preference is to use services and directives.

Comment: A simple example would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is too broad to be answered fully however here is some hints :

1. use directive/components when you need to manipulate the DOM
2. Controller should have the less code possible. Put the logic/server call in a service layer.
3. If you need a complex navigation system with multiple controller sharing data you might want to check ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It's a state machine in which you can nested state and their associated views. The controller of child state inherits from parent state allowing sharing datas.
4. If not ui-router 2 way of sharing data in a controller : events ($on, $emit), storing the data shared in a service and use $watch to watch for changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would really appreciate a very short and simple example with a couple of directives/services, 1 controller. Need to visualize how these things hang together. Don't need anything complex...

Comment: that too dependant of your choice, if i go for a ui-router sample and you won't go for it, most of what i'll show about how they hang together will fall. About how they hang together that's pretty simple : controller use service, directive are used in template and can have services injected, for the binding of directives check the documentation or tons of sample on the net. There is already too much to say just for directives.

Comment: no problem, just check the component one by one and if you don't understand, google it you will end up there aniway if you find or if you need to ask a question :)